# CSV attachment for a Stack Overflow post

Tags: support, editor

I was trying to attach a csv file to one of my questions to include some sample data to help reproduce the problem. But I couldn't find a way to attach a file to the question.

How can you attach a csv file to a Stack Overflow question?

Comment: 1. This should have been asked on meta, since it's a question about the site itself. 2. Just copy a **sample** of the data into the question directly, and apply code markup.

Comment: See [ask]. Note: You are required to provide all necessary information **in** the question, no links! And you might want to learn how your OS supports copy&past of text.

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow posts do not natively support attachments.  In general, most attachments that would be added are either extraneous or signs of a poorly scoped question.  Sample data should be of sufficiently small size to avoid requiring attachments to communicate.  Otherwise, you violate the M (minimal) in [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or are just asking a question that is way too broad.  I suggest trying to break the problem into smaller pieces and ask questions about those pieces.

That being said, if you really want to include an attachment, you should host the attachment on an external site (e.g. github) and provide a share link to the resource.  Even in these cases, your question must still be able to stand on its own without access to the link.

Comment: thanks ryanyuyu. @Carcigenicate's idea to mark the data as code worked great for me.