# Feature Request: being able to upload small .csv files

Tags: feature-request

Often I have data science related questions.  But in order to give reproducible examples I need to give a viewer data which leaves me with two options:

1. I can write a script to randomly generate data, which distracts from the question itself and is time-consuming.
2. The other option is simply printing some of my data off and adding "," between values so people can have a makeshift CSV file to work with.

It would be nice to simply upload small CSV files to supply sample data which is relevant to a question. There could be a reasonable limit implemented to the size of the files, for example a 10x10 limit would be easy for the site to manage.

In the comments I suggested Stack Overflow could dump the data after a certain time or if the question was answered, one commenter inferred that this meant the data was not important in the first place.  If your question concerns a data visualization function, the visual answer of the question would still be valuable after the fact.

I am not the first person to encounter this issue even if I'm not the best at making the case for this to be a feature. Please also consider the first question here:

1. [What is the best way to provide necessary data that cannot be provided via the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348815/what-is-the-best-way-to-provide-necessary-data-that-cannot-be-provided-via-the-m) ,
2. [How can a questioner post Excel data?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368179/how-can-a-questioner-post-excel-data)
3. [CSV attachment for a Stack Overflow post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335567/csv-attachment-for-a-stack-overflow-post)

Comment: Why not simply put the data in the question if it's that small? Why does it need to be uploaded?

Comment: It's not that simple, as I explained that involves printing the data out then adding  a comma to each individual entry.  I guess you could write a string manipulation script.

10x10 was not a hard limit I assumed there would be hosting issues so it was not meant to be an exact number, just indicating a small limit.

Comment: "*that involves printing the data out then adding a comma to each individual entry*" yes, which gives you a CSV data. My question is why does this need to be *a file* which is uploaded, as opposed to taking that same data and putting *just the text* as part of the question?

Comment: I know and as I have explained that would mean printing the data and then adding a comma individually to each entry

Comment: go to R right now and print a csv you will not get commas inbetween each data entry

Comment: Which...you need to do in order to get a CSV file and you're suggesting uploading of CSV files. Thus at this point you already have the CSV data. Why does *uploading* make more sense when you already have it and you can copy/paste it in the question?

Comment: If you already have CSV file, why not copy the 1st 5 lines of the file onto the question, as-is. Then format into a code-block. I'm confused with the "*printing some of my data off and adding "," between values*" If you truly have CSV data then you don't need to add any commas?

Comment: You are missing the entire point.  Sometimes after you have done many many transformations from an original csv you are left with a matrix which you do not have a csv for.  At this point printing sufficient data points and then formatting it is actually not simple.

Comment: I don't know R, but on the [tag:r] tag there is some guidance on how to provide an mcve: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Comment: Visually the code chunk it huge and looks ugly, why would you not just have a button "upload data" and supply a csv it would be much cleaner

Comment: "*At this point printing sufficient data points and then formatting it is actually not simple.*" then the FR doesn't make sense on a different level - how would uploading a CSV help at all, since you need to convert that matrix into a CSV *anyway*. Your proposal is to allow supplying CSV data but also you're saying it's hard to provide CSV data. What am I missing? Why does uploading change anything here?

Comment: there are functions in python and R that write csv's I'm telling you as some one that works in data it would be simple to create a csv that way then upload it.  And why on earth would you want a huge chunk of the question taken up by that. 10x10 was an example.  What happens if its 100x100?  it gets visually rediculous and for some issues you may want a larger dataset like that.  What if you're supplying floats?

Comment: Go to r or python right now and generate a matrix either and then answer my question with a 100x100 chunk of data use np.eye(100) and see how easy it is to supply it like that then afterwards tell me it looks good.

Comment: "*What happens if its 100x100?*" is that really *minimal* reproducible example, in that case?

Comment: It depends on the question for some stats simulations it may not be.

Comment: I don't see why stack can host image files but small csvs is such a terrible idea?  What if the question itself is about some structure in the data?

Comment: "*I don't see why stack can host image files*" it doesn't. They are hosted by Imgur

Comment: Still a tiny csv is not such a rediculous thing to host.  Can be discarded after the questuion is answered as well.

Comment: Also, your question about 100x100 data does come in conflict with your FR which suggests 10x10 as the limit. That's the very reason I asked why not include it in the question if it's that small. And your response was that it might be *bigger*? Can you please clarify what you're asking for here because I was basing my discussion in comments to the text in the question. Yet you seem to retort with information that's neither in the question, nor something I can reasonably guess.

Comment: "*Can be discarded after the questuion is answered as well.*" - This is a terrible idea and you are suggesting absolutely abusing Stack Overflow!!! This is not a help desk. If the dataset is discarded *and it's crucial for the question*, then the question loses value for future visitors. The whole point of asking a question *is to help future visitors*. If the dataset is discarded and the question still has value, then the dataset wasn't crucial.

Comment: Again 10x10 or 100x100 are not exact figures it would be decided by some downstream stack staff I geuss.  It was not meant to be a perfect limit.

Comment: Imagine you're trying to ask a question that invovles changing the setting on a heatmap for instance.  There are tons of these questions all overstack, the visual feedback which is specific to the data in question is actually very important.  It can take ages generating a dataset that will look like the data you have.  If the question is about the options on these visualization functions it would definitely be helpful.

Comment: This question still makes no sense. If you have _already_ made the csv, why can't you just copy a portion of the data from it?

Comment: @AngusCampbell "_there are functions in python and R that write csv's_" yes so you can just copy the CSV and put it in your question... You could even come up with a small script of your own that nicely formats it as a markdown table.

Comment: "*If your question concerns a data visualization function the visual answer of the question would still be valuable after the fact.*" so, can the question be answered *again* later by somebody who doesn't have the dataset?

Comment: Relevant: [What is the best way to provide necessary data that cannot be provided via the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348815/what-is-the-best-way-to-provide-necessary-data-that-cannot-be-provided-via-the-m), [How can a questioner post Excel data?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368179/how-can-a-questioner-post-excel-data), [CSV attachment for a Stack Overflow post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335567/csv-attachment-for-a-stack-overflow-post)

Comment: A bunch of argumentative comments questioning people's knowledge, experience, motivations, etc. have been removed.  Please stick to the merits of the feature request and not the people discussing it.

Comment: In case it isn't clear: "go to R right now and print a csv you will not get commas inbetween each data entry" - if you are printing a CSV in your R environment, that implies that you **have** a CSV file. What you do from here is to **open the CSV file in an ordinary text editor**. You will notice that it **already contains** the necessary commas etc., because that's what "CSV file" **means**. Copy and paste text from the text editor into the question, and apply whatever appropriate formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example in Python of generating some CSV data directly in the terminal window, which can then be copied and pasted without having to look for a separate file on your hard drive:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.eye(10) # for example
>>> # "Save" to an in-memory "file"
>>> import io
>>> text = io.StringIO()
>>> np.savetxt(text, np.eye(10), delimiter=',', fmt='%d')
>>> # and then view it:
>>> print(text.getvalue())
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
```

> I still just think this looks really ugly and is distracting from the question itself.

We can use Markdown to format the data as a table:

```
| a | b | c |
|---|---|---|
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
```

produces

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |

Generating this programmatically is left as an exercise. Unfortunately a header row is required, which makes it not great for Numpy data.

If you are trying to create a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), better to write code that produces the desired input, even if it's ugly:

```
import IO
import numpy as np

fake_csv = (
    '1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\n0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\n'
    '0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\n0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0\n'
    '0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0\n0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0\n'
    '0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0\n0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0\n'
    '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0\n0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1\n'
)

with IO.StringIO(fake_csv) as data:
    my_array = np.loadtxt(fake_csv, delimiter=',')

# proceed with the rest of the example
```

Answer (score 14):

It's not needed to upload a CSV file. You can generate the CSV file from R or Python or whichever your programming environment is. Open the CSV file in a text editor, and copy and paste it into your question. Example in R:

```
> data(mtcars)
> head(mtcars,10)
                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360        14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
> write.csv(head(mtcars,10),"cars.csv")
```

This generates `cars.csv` with the following contents:

```
"","mpg","cyl","disp","hp","drat","wt","qsec","vs","am","gear","carb"
"Mazda RX4",21,6,160,110,3.9,2.62,16.46,0,1,4,4
"Mazda RX4 Wag",21,6,160,110,3.9,2.875,17.02,0,1,4,4
"Datsun 710",22.8,4,108,93,3.85,2.32,18.61,1,1,4,1
"Hornet 4 Drive",21.4,6,258,110,3.08,3.215,19.44,1,0,3,1
"Hornet Sportabout",18.7,8,360,175,3.15,3.44,17.02,0,0,3,2
"Valiant",18.1,6,225,105,2.76,3.46,20.22,1,0,3,1
"Duster 360",14.3,8,360,245,3.21,3.57,15.84,0,0,3,4
"Merc 240D",24.4,4,146.7,62,3.69,3.19,20,1,0,4,2
"Merc 230",22.8,4,140.8,95,3.92,3.15,22.9,1,0,4,2
"Merc 280",19.2,6,167.6,123,3.92,3.44,18.3,1,0,4,4
```

As you can see, it has commas.

Comment: I still just think this looks really ugly and is distracting from the question itself.  And again I feel like there would be situations this would be useful in.  I'm gonna let this questions sit here and get upvoted or downvoted and see if people agree with me.

Comment: @AngusCampbell I agree with you that such a block of data can be distracting in the sense of not being needed to understand a question. However, many times reading and understanding the data _is_ important for answering the question, so it is useful to be able to see the data within the body of the question. If the block gets longer then it automatically gets a scroll bar so it will never be a huge block taking up all of the screen.

Comment: Another advantage is that it is more safe: you can see which data you are going to copy to your own computer, instead of trusting that a csv file download contains the data for the question and nothing else.

Comment: That's a very good point.  Hadn't considered that.

Comment: This seems like a totally fine solution to me, as someone who answers questions on the R tag I would be perfectly happy if someone shared the data this way. I wouldn’t be happy clicking on file download links on my work computer when I have no idea what they might contain.